# How to observe when a payment was cancelled using StoreKit 2

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I have a framework and when people make purchases I need to know what's going on. I don't make the purchases for the people, I just observe what's going on.

When using StoreKit1 I use a `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` to observer the transaction queue. Then when a payment fails I can check the error code to see whether it was cancelled. However, I can't figure out how to do this in StoreKit 2? Anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score -2):

You can still listen to updates of transactions in StoreKit 2.

e.g.:

```
private func newTransactionListenerTask() -> Task<Void, Never> {
    Task(priority: .background) {
        for await verificationResult in Transaction.updates {
            self.handle(updatedTransaction: verificationResult)
        }
    }
}
```

You of course would need to store a reference to the `Task` returned. You should call this as soon as your app starts. It will receive all transaction changes while your App is in foreground. If you missed something while you app was in the background you will receive it on startup.

for more information:

[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/transaction/3851206-updates)

[wwdc 2021 at around 15:20](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10114/)

Comment: This is for transactions but this doesn't get fired when someone starts and then cancels a transaction though does it?

Comment: I'm using this structure like the documentation says, but it doesn't fire when a subscription is cancelled.

Comment: You don't know about the customer has canceled (or is about to cancel) a subscription unless you have a server listening to App Store Server Notifications.